# Sort one column based on another

Tags: bash, sorting

I need to sort one column based on another such as this:

File:

```
a1 10
a1 11
a1 12
a1 8
a2 9
a2 14
a2 6
```

Output:

```
a1 8
a1 10
a1 11
a1 12
a2 6
a2 9
a2 14
```

I tried this command

```
sort -k1,1 -nk2,2 file
```

but it only sorts numerically the second column, how could I achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2):

It is a small change in the command:

```
sort -k1,1 -k2n,2 file
```

Comment: `sort -k1,1 -k2n` is enough

Answer (score 0):

```
sort -V file
```

> **-V**, **--version-sort**
>   - - - - natural sort of (version) numbers within text